# How Fitnesse differs from JUnit?

Tags: fitnesse

Can anyone help me describing how function of Fitnesse differs from the JUnit.

I have been working with Fitnesse for few days. I am asking this question because I am still trying to understand the objective of the tool. I went through some of the web Articles, they were saying:
JUnit is to build the Code Right and Fitnesse is to build the Right code. But I want to know how?

Great if we can get some examples...

Thanks in Advance

---Sreenisha S---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference for me is the target audience.

JUnit (and other unit test frameworks) are targeted to developers validating their code (still) does what they expected it to do. The test definition, execution and interpreting of output is expected to be done by programmers. The toolkit is designed for white-box testing, although it can be used for other goals as well.

FitNesse is intended for black-box testing, based on what the functionality has to be, not on how it is implemented. The intention is that domain knowledge suffices to create tests (or at least add test cases), execute them and get meaningful information from the test output.

In my usage programmers also work with FitNesse, but they use it to define integration tests working against an installed system to validate end-to-end behavior. We for instance test web applications with a browser (using Selenium) and SOAP interfaces offered by the system.
Unit tests are used for component tests (often with external components replaced by fakes/mocks) in a (dedicated) test process.

Does this help at all?